# How to get the selected UILocalNotification information

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have created a iphone app in which I have am using `UILocalNotification`s. It works fine. But now, When i click on the notification i want to get the row number of the notification that i clicked. Is it possible?

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// Notification details
localNotif.alertBody = [eventText text];
// Set the action button
localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

// Specify custom data for the notification
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notifications don't have row numbers. Explain in more detail what you're doing and show the code that posts the notification and what you want the row number for (presumably used with a table view).

Comment: I just want the notification index number that i selected.

Comment: Show your code, your question and comments don't make sense. Are you talking about an `NSNotification`, or an `IBAction`, or something else? I have no idea currently.

Answer (score 0):

When a user triggers a local notification to open your app you will receive a callback to either `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey`.

Once you receive the callback you can get the associated `UILocalNotification` and access its properties. Generally, you're interested in the `userInfo` and the keys that you added to it. You can add whatever you want.

I'd generally stay away from index numbers because they can change depending on what you're doing. Instead, consider giving each notification a unique identity (like a GUID) and using that to find whatever associated data you keep inside the app.